# NullPointerException while reading file into array

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception, bufferedreader

I've been getting null pointer exception while reading a file into an array. i realized that the exception appears when it is null and something else is required. The array minefield has already been initialized. The exception happens on " minefield[i][j]=input.charAt(j)+"";"

I'm trying to read in a file with this format:

```
#of row
#of column
abcd
efgh
ijkl
```

This is the code:

```
     try {
            BufferedReader in =new BufferedReader (new FileReader(name+".txt"));
            String input=in.readLine();      
            row = Integer.parseInt(input);
            input=in.readLine();
            col = Integer.parseInt(input);
            int c =0;
            input=in.readLine();
            for (int i=0;i<row;i++){
            input=in.readLine();
            for (int j=0;j<col;j++){
                  System.out.println (input.charAt(j));
                  minefield[i][j]=input.charAt(j)+"";
               }
            }
            System.out.println("The file has been loaded");
            in.close();
         }
            catch(IOException iox){
               System.out.println ("Error reading file");
            }
```

Your help is greatly appreciated. 
Edit: Sorry i left something out.

Comment: Which are your values for i and j?

Comment: What is `row`? Are there `row` lines in the file?

Comment: Show us the stack trace. It will have the exact line number where the exception occurred.

Comment: I've added the missing information.
The exception happens "minefield[i][j]=input.charAt(j)+"";"

Answer (score 1):

Method readLine() returns null when the end of the stream is reached, but you don't check it.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine--

Answer (score 0):

Check that `minefield` has been initialized.

Simply declaring `minefield` is not enough as it default to null.

```
private String[][] minefield;
```

You need to assign a new `String[][]` array to it.

```
private String[][] minefield = new String[4][5];
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `name` and `minefield` are initialized. Then, I would rewrite your code to safeguard against a mismatch between whatever value you have in `row` and the number of lines in the file:

```
try {
    BufferedReader in =new BufferedReader (new FileReader(name+".txt"));
    String input;
    for (int i=0;i<row;i++){
        input=in.readLine();
        if (input == null) {
           throw new IOException("Expected " + row +
               " lines in the file; only found " + i + " lines");
        }
        for (int j=0;j<col;j++){
            System.out.println (input.charAt(j));
            minefield[i][j]=input.charAt(j)+"";
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The file has been loaded");
    in.close();
 }
 catch(IOException iox){
     System.out.println ("Error reading file");
 }
```

**EDIT** Now that you've updated your question with more complete code, it's clear what the problem is. After you read the number of rows and columns from the file, you are reading one line for each row, but you are reading one additional line before you start the loop for the number of rows. Unless the file contains a blank line, this is causing you to overrun the end of the file.

Comment: This would still give me the exception at "minefield[i][j]=input.charAt(j)+""; "

Comment: @user1337628 - Then `minefield` must not be initialized. With the check for `null` before the `j` loop, there's no way for `input` to be `null` there, and `minefield` is the only other source of a NPE.

Comment: Ah, i forgot to reinitialize minefield
Thanks for you help

Answer (score 0):

Given the contents of your input file, you have an extra `input = in.readLine();` that doesn't have a matching line entry:

```
...
int c =0;
input=in.readLine();   <-- remove this line
for (int i=0;i<row;i++){
...
```